# What is the nfunction of .WillOnce(Return(n)) in google mock?

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

```
EXPECT_CALL(turtle, GetX())
.WillOnce(Return(100))
```

What is the function of the above action *.WillOnce(Return(100))*? Does it verify that the value 100 is returned exactly once from *GetX()*? Or does it make the function *GetX()* to return the value 100?

Comment: What did you miss specifically from Google Mock's reference documentation?

Comment: The answer to this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in the [gmock docs](https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/github.com/google/googletest/+/HEAD/googlemock/docs/for_dummies.md#setting-expectations), this will make the test fail if method `GetX` on the mock `turtle` is NOT executed exactly once (see "Cardinalities: How Many Times Will It Be Called"). Otherwise the test will pass (unless it will fail in some other point) and the `GetX` method will return `100` wherever it was called.